# Are hard-coded math operations performed at compile time or run time in lua

Tags: lua, solar2d

I know not all compilers do that but does lua do it?

I have this written `15 * 1.75 * 2` I can just leave a comment line and leave the calculation there, in order make it still understandable but leaving it like the way it is better and I am curious.

Comment: Depends on the version, here you can inspect the bytecode: https://www.luac.nl/ Modern Lua optimizes that. In any case, use the more readable version unless absolutely required.

Comment: You can always chose to write the more readable value as comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Math expressions are calculated at compile time in Lua 5.1+ (thanks to Luke100000 for the link in the comments).
The only exceptions are `inf`s and `NaN`. A Lua bytecode contains only finite numeric constants; "dangerous" math operations resulting in `inf`/`NaN` are deferred to runtime.